# How to do coding in ClickOnce installer?

Tags: c#, installation, clickonce

I have to create a folder by doing coding in ClickOnce installer. I need to add plugins to my application which i want to download in a separate folder. for that i need to add a folder where all my plugins will be downloaded. Whenever any new plugin is available with the main application then it'll get downloaded in this custom folder(say Documents and Files) and then when i run my application then it asks me that updates are available, do i want to download?
Please help.

Comment: i made installer of an application by publishing it through clickonce installer. I succeeded so far but now i want to introduce plugins in my main application. i want to put all these plugins in a new folder like Documents and Settings. for that i need to do coding in ClickOnce as I want this folder to get created before my main application is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need Full Trust to access other folders on the installed system.

You can create a separate initial installer for you application, but it still uses Click Once mechanics.

I suggest you explore your options under "Prerequisites" in the Click Once settings for the project and [adding a Custom prereq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429%28VS.80%29.aspx).